# At the end of my animation keyframes, in the graph editor, the red line isn't straight

Tags: graph-editor

At the end of my animation keyframes, in the graph editor, the red line isn't straight.
Why and how to make it straight?

[image]

Comment: most likely you have another keyframe at the end (hard to tell, since you cropped the image) that is using  bézier type interpolation.

Comment: There's no other keyframe. I've checked by zooming out very far. 
The last square on the image, is the last keyframe.

Comment: Hard to help you further without more info.